# Relationship between foreign keys and the LINQ Include opeator

Tags: linq, foreign-keys

I am struggling with a LINQ query using EF Core.  In short, I have four tables linked with foreign keys but cannot seem to write the correct LINQ functions.  Here is a diagram of the tables in the database:
[image]

What I want to do is create a LINQ query that generates the same data as the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT [Row],[Col],[TextLines]
FROM dbo.[Models] m
INNER JOIN dbo.[Table] t
ON m.ID=t.ModelID
INNER JOIN dbo.[TableCells] tc
ON t.ID=tc.TableID
INNER JOIN [TableCellsLines] tcl
ON tc.ID=tcl.TableCellId
WHERE m.ModelType='table' AND Part=3 AND Chapter=1 AND Lesson=1
ORDER BY tc.[Row], tc.[Col]
```

Here are the SQL Statements used to create the Links:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.[Table]
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Table_Model FOREIGN KEY (ModelID) REFERENCES dbo.[Models](ID)

ALTER TABLE dbo.[TableCells]
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TableCells_Tables FOREIGN KEY(TableID) REFERENCES dbo.[Table](ID)

ALTER TABLE dbo.[TableCellsLines]
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_TableCellsLines_TableCells FOREIGN KEY(TableCellId) REFERENCES dbo.[TableCells](ID)
```

Now, I was thinking that the constraints would allow me to do something like:

```
    var Model = TEASPrepContext.Models.Where(m => m.ModelType == ModelType && m.Part == Part &&  m.Chapter == Chapter && m.Lesson == Lesson)
                    .Include(m => m.Tables)
                    .Include(t=>t.TableCells)
                    .Include(tc=>tc.TableCellsLines)
                    .Select( ... )
```

However, the compiler will not allow the second and third Include calls.  Obviously, I do not understand the relationship between foreign keys and LINQ.  I would be grateful for anyone who could offer a solution and, just as importantly, a document or tutorial that could explain how LINQ and foreign keys work.

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

`Include` not for querying but for loading related data. Usually it is not needed at all if you do not load data for modification. Also after `Select`, `GroupBy` it is discarded.

Your query is a set of `SelectMany` operators which is readable only with Query Syntaxt:

```cs
 var query =
    from m in TEASPrepContext.Models
    from t in m.Tables
    from tc in t.TableCells
    from tcl in tc.TableCellsLines
    where m.ModelType == ModelType && m.Part == Part && m.Chapter == Chapter && m.Lesson == Lesson
    orderby tc.Row, tc.Col
    select new 
    {
         tc.Row, 
         tc.Col,
         tcl.TextLines
    };
```